# focusout for nested component angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

i am new to angular 2 
and i have an issue
i created a multi select component and i added it inside a form 
as in image 1 : 
[image: image 1]

code for multi selection component inside form :

```
<app-multi-selection  [multiSelection]="multiSelectionObject" (selectedProductsCodes)="getSelectedProductCodes($event)" (focusout) = "focusOutFunction()" ></app-multi-selection>
```

i want to hide the list of check boxes when i click out of this component
but the problem when i click on any where in side the form  outside the app-multi-selection focusout is not working .

is their any way to take an event when un focusing any component ?

Comment: Have you tried to use blur() event?

Answer (score -1):

It is called click-outside. For example look at [Outside-click directive for Angular 2](https://github.com/chliebel/angular2-click-outside)

As requested I am adding the code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
  @Output() clickOutside = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
  onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement) {
    if (!targetElement) {
      return;
    }

    const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement)
      && !(targetElement instanceof HTMLAnchorElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.promoClickOutside.emit(null);
    }
  }
}
```